# how to play different songs on left and right channels simultaneously on android device

Tags: android, playback, channel

Is it possible to play 2 different songs simultaneously on the left and the right channel on android device? I searched a lot to see if `MediaPlayer` class provides APIs to support that but in vain.

`SoundPool` has the file size restriction and I need to play files larger than 2 MB. Basically, I have a android player which plays single zone. Now I need the player to play 2 different songs simultaneously on the left and right output (speakers/earphone etc.) Is this possible? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use two instances of AudioTrack.

I create plenty of them.

Usually devices let you go up to 24 or so.

All you need is two :-)

[android play sound with AudioTrack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11203474/android-play-sound-with-audiotrack)

The setVolume() method takes two parameters, one for left, one for right.

Comment: Can this be achieved creating two instances of the MediaPlayer as well as I see it has the method setVolume(float leftVolume, float rightVolume)? The reason I want to go this route is because my single zone code already has the media player object and would be easier to create another instance.

Comment: Try it out and let us know.

Comment: Awesome.. Thanks MazeHatter! I was able to achieve this creating two instances of the Media Player.

Comment: @deepakszone Did you solve your problem? I need a solution :D

Comment: @NyamkhuuBuyanjargal did you try this? mMediaPlayer1 = new MediaPlayer();
mMediaPlayer2= new MediaPlayer();